# std::deque.front() выполняется 200 миллисекунд, как это возможно?

Tags: java, c++, многопоточность, очередь, jni

Очень странные вещи происходят

Прежде всего я использую `jni` android (если это важно)

У меня есть `safe-thread` имплементация `std::deque` с одно стороны в одном треде я наполняю эту очередь с другой стороны в другом треде я забираю с очереди

Я не могу понять почему метод который вытаскивает из очереди `front()` берет около 200 миллисекунд на выполнение?

Имплементация очереди

```
 #ifndef SAFE_QUEUE
#define SAFE_QUEUE

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include "frame_manager.h"
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string>

#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

namespace hello_ar
{
// A threadsafe-queue.
template<class T>
class safe_queue
{
public:
    safe_queue(std::string const &name)
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    ~safe_queue()
    = default;

    // Add an element to the queue.
    void enqueue(T t)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        m_queue.push_back(t);
        m_condition.notify_one();
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return static_cast<int>(m_queue.size());
    }

    // Get the "front"-element.
    // If the queue is empty, wait till a element is avaiable.
    T dequeue(bool flag)
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t5 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        T val;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

            while (m_queue.empty())
            {
                // release lock as long as the wait and reaquire it afterwards.
                m_condition.wait(lock);
            }

            val = m_queue.front();

            if (flag)
            {
                m_queue.pop_front();
            }
        }

        return val;
    }

    T dequeue()
    {
        return dequeue(true);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        std::deque<std::shared_ptr<FrameManager>>().swap(m_queue);
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_queue.empty();
    }

public:
    std::deque<T> m_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
    std::string m_name;
};
}
#endi
```

Наполнение очереди происходит с помощью `enqueue`

Как я сказал есть еще другой класс и другой метод который выполняется на другом потоке и вытаскивает из очереди, что там есть.

```
void VideoRender::Draw(const glm::mat4 &projection_mat, //
                       const glm::mat4 &view_mat, //
                       glm::mat4 &model_mat //
)
{
    if (!m_shaderProgram)
    {
        LOGE("shader_program is null.");
        return;
    }

    if (m_bPauseFrameLoading)
        return;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point now_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    long long int delta_from_last_time = duration_cast<microseconds>(now_time - m_last_time).count();

    if (!m_fifo.empty() && delta_from_last_time >= util::FRAME_INTERVAL_MSEC * 1000)
    {
        m_last_time = now_time;

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        m_FrameManager = m_fifo.m_queue.front();

        long long int durationn = duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - t4).count();
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "front", "front  %s::: %s", m_fifo.getName().c_str(), std::to_string(durationn).c_str());

        m_fifo.m_queue.pop_front();

        std::vector<GLfloat> const &vertices = m_FrameManager->getVertices();
        std::vector<GLfloat> const &textures = m_FrameManager->getTextures();
        std::vector<GLuint> const &indices = m_FrameManager->getIndices();

        glDeleteTextures(1, &m_textureId);

        glGenTextures(1, &m_textureId);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureId);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //
                     0, //
                     GL_RGB,  //
                     m_FrameManager->getImageWidth(), //
                     m_FrameManager->getImageHeight(), //
                     0, //
                     GL_RGB, //
                     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, //
                     m_FrameManager->GetImageData().data()//
        );
    }

    glUseProgram(m_shaderProgram);

    if (m_FrameManager != nullptr)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriVertices), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_FrameManager->getVertices().data());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriVertices));
        glVertexAttribPointer(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriUvs), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_FrameManager->getTextures().data());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriUvs));

        glUniform2f(m_uniform_center_xy, static_cast<GLfloat>(m_centerX), static_cast<GLfloat>(m_centerY));

        //---------------------------------------------
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureId);
        glUniform1i(m_uniformTexture, 0);

        model_mat = glm::rotate(model_mat, util::AXIS_ALIGNMENT, glm::vec3(1.F));
        model_mat = glm::rotate(model_mat, m_modelRotation, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        model_mat = glm::scale(model_mat, glm::vec3(m_modelSize));
        glm::mat4 mvp_mat = projection_mat * view_mat * model_mat;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniformMvpMat, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp_mat));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, static_cast<GLsizei>(m_FrameManager->getIndices().size()), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, m_FrameManager->getIndices().data());

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriVertices));
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(static_cast<GLuint>(m_attriUvs));

    glUseProgram(0);
    util::CheckGlError("VideoRender::Draw()");
}
```

Это длинный метод и на самом деле вам не нужно знать все, что здесь происходит, но я хочу обратить внимание на строку

```
 m_FrameManager = m_fifo.m_queue.front();
```

Здесь я специально сделал `m_queue` public чтоб убрать возможные сомнения , теперь я напрямую обращаюсь в мою имплементацию очереди от туда я напрямую беру `std::deque` и уже на ней вызываю `front()` , чтоб получить обьект

Так же сразу же этого метода есть следующая строка в которой я логирую время выполнения

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "front", "front  %s::: %s", m_fifo.getName().c_str(), std::to_string(durationn).c_str());
```

И вот время выполнения

```
13:03:27.137  E/front: front  video_render::: 213285
13:03:27.446  E/front: front  video_render::: 276841
13:03:27.710  E/front: front  video_render::: 238782
13:03:27.936  E/front: front  video_render::: 197096
13:03:28.171  E/front: front  video_render::: 216234
13:03:28.400  E/front: front  video_render::: 208742
13:03:28.620  E/front: front  video_render::: 205443
13:03:28.869  E/front: front  video_render::: 227723
13:03:29.117  E/front: front  video_render::: 217806
13:03:29.345  E/front: front  video_render::: 207497
13:03:29.575  E/front: front  video_render::: 214358
13:03:29.806  E/front: front  video_render::: 216148
13:03:30.006  E/front: front  video_render::: 186434
13:03:30.207  E/front: front  video_render::: 188939
13:03:30.414  E/front: front  video_render::: 192210
13:03:30.620  E/front: front  video_render::: 189335
13:03:30.821  E/front: front  video_render::: 186266
13:03:31.025  E/front: front  video_render::: 186589
```

Так что вопрос, как такое возможно, что время выполнения стандартного метода `front()` 200 милисекунд?

**EDIT**

Тип обьекта в очереди `std::shared_ptr<FrameManager>`

```
struct FrameManager
{
private:
    std::vector<GLfloat> m_vertices;
    std::vector<GLfloat> m_textures;
    std::vector<GLuint> m_indices;

    std::vector<GLuint> m_indicess;
    std::vector<GLuint> m_indicesss;
    std::vector<GLuint> m_indicessss;

    std::vector<unsigned char> m_imageData;
    GeometryLoader m_geometryLoader;
    NativeCodec &m_nativeCodec;
    bool m_isGeometryLoaded = false;
    bool m_isTexLoaded = false;

....

}
```

Comment: какой тип элементов в m_fifo.m_queue? Возможно там происходит копирование тяжёлого объекта

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon добавил в вопрос

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вы используете ```high_resolution_clock``` в разных потоках?

Comment: @isnullxbh вы хотите сказать, что каждый кор считает по своему время? Даже если так, то все равно `high_resolution_clock` я использую только в методе `Draw()` а этот метод у меня крутиться в одном потоке...

Comment: На первой итерации при front произойдёт лишь увеличение счётчика в shared_ptr, но уже при следующем front и далее старые данные, которые были в shared_ptr нужно удалить, т.к. на них больше нет ссылок(удалили из m_fifo.m_queue, перезаписали m_FrameManager), а у вас там 100500 массивов, вот на их удаление и уходит 200ms